# How to assign two lists in a linq query with some conditions?

Tags: c#, linq, list, indices

I've two lists and I assign one of them this way:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
{
    if ((index >= 525 && index <= 544) || (index >= 600 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 1079) || (index >= 1300 && index <= 1439))
        return 0;
    else if (index >= 1080 && index <= 1299)
        return 1;
    else if (index >= 545 && index <= 599)
        return 3;
    else if (index >= 750 && index <= 809)
        return 4;
    else
        return 2;
}).ToList();
```

My second list is named lst2. I want to assign it "0" or "1" depending on my first list query. So, if query is "1" or "2", lst2's same indices and previous indices that are "0" value, should be "1". If the query list is "3" or "4", lst2's same indices and previous indices that are "1" value, should be "0". In addition, if the query's first indice(s) has "3" or "4" value, then lst2's same indice(s) should be "0". For example;

```
query = {3,3,3,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,4,4}
lst2  = {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** *If query's any indice has 3 or 4 value, lst2's same indice must have 0 value. If query's any indice has 3 or 4 value AND previous indice has 0 value, lst2's same indices must have 0 value. Likewise; If query's any indice has 1 or 2 value, lst2's same indice must have 1 value. If query's any indice has 1 or 2 value AND previous indice has 0 value, lst2's same indices must have 1 value.*

Comment: The list has 1440 elements, in your sample data(`query` and `lst2`) you're showing only an excerpt, is that correct? In general LINQ is not the best option if indices (+ previous indices) are so important. Use a `for`-loop.

Comment: Yup. Seconded. Use a for loop and just write to both lists at the same time. You're not getting much benefit from the linq in terms of deferred execution or anything so no need to be too attached to it.

Comment: That's correct. lst2 should has same size and this is an excerpt. How can I acomplish?

Comment: I think you should explain what you want in more detail. I still dont understand when you want to have a 0 or 1 in lst2. Maybe the use case would help. Could be possible that you do something unneccessarely complicated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach, only filling the tracing 0's when needed. Performance wise it's still best to loop reversed, but I only just saw T_D already did that, so as far as the lookahead -> lookback goes, the below is basically the same, but with other syntax and a different trailing 0 filler.

```
    var arr = new int[query.Count];
    int cnt = query.Count - 1, toappendindex = -1;
    Func<int,int,int> getval = (ind, val) =>
    {
        if (val == 3 || val == 4) return  0;
        if (val == 2 || val == 1) return  1;
        if (ind == cnt) return -1;
        return arr[ind + 1];
    };   
    for (int ind = cnt; ind >= 0; ind-- ) 
    {
        if ((arr[ind] = getval(ind,query[ind])) == -1)
            toappendindex = ind; //only if there are trailing 0's
    }
    if (toappendindex > 0) 
        for (; toappendindex < arr.Length; toappendindex++) arr[toappendindex] = arr[toappendindex - 1];

    //var lst2 = arr.ToList(); if list is needed instead of array, otherwise arr could be used directly
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this.

```
        List<int> query = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
        {
            if ((index >= 525 && index <= 544) || (index >= 600 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 1079) || (index >= 1300 && index <= 1439))
                return 0;
            else if (index >= 1080 && index <= 1299)
                return 1;
            else if (index >= 545 && index <= 599)
                return 3;
            else if (index >= 750 && index <= 809)
                return 4;
            else
                return 2;
        }).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("{", string.Join(",", query.ToArray()), "}"));

        List<int> lst2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select((n, index) =>
        {
            if (query[index] == 1 || query[index] == 2)
                return 1;
            else if (query[index] == 3 || query[index] == 4)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                int retval = 1;
                //look ahead
                for (int i = index; i < query.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (query[i] == 1 || query[i] == 2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (query[i] == 3 || query[i] == 4)
                    {
                        retval = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return retval;
            }
        }).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("{", string.Join(",", lst2.ToArray()), "}"));
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for. You can replace List with var if you like. I just like it strong-typed so that I can easily check the output.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I've revized the question with more details.

Comment: I have modified the code to account for the last 0's.

Comment: The output of {2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0} is now {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need:

```
    int n = 1440;
    byte[] query = new byte[n];
    byte[] lst2 = new byte[n];
    byte mode = 0;
    bool first = true;
    for(int index = n-1; index >= 0; index--)
    {

        if ((index >= 525 && index <= 544) || (index >= 600 && index <= 749) || (index >= 810 && index <= 1079) || (index >= 1300 && index <= 1439))
            query[index] = 0;
        else if (index >= 1080 && index <= 1299)
            query[index] = 1;
        else if (index >= 545 && index <= 599)
            query[index] = 3;
        else if (index >= 750 && index <= 809)
            query[index] = 4;
        else
            query[index] = 2;

        if(query[index] == 3 || query[index] == 4)
        {
            mode = 0;
            lst2[index] = 0;
        }
        else if(query[index] == 1 || query[index] == 2)
        {
            if(first)
            {
                //change ending zeros to 1
                for(int j=index+1; j < n; j++)
                    lst2[j] = 1;

                first = false;
            }
            mode = 1;
            lst2[index] = 1;
        }
        else
        {   
            lst2[index] = mode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works some wrongly. For example; if query = {2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0} then lst2 should be {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}. But this solution's result is {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}. What can be done?

Comment: I dont know the rule for the ending zeros. just continuing the previous mode?

Comment: You are right. In fact; if query's first values are not 0, then lst2's same indices should be 0. If query's last values are 0, then lst2's same indices should be 1. Sorry, I think I didn't say anything about this.